# differential form of charge for pi_4(S^3) or pi_4(S^2)

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

How to write a 4-form of topological charge which would correspond to non-zero element of
the homotopy group $\pi_4(S^3)$ or $\pi_4(S^2)$ (both are equal to $Z_2$) ? ?

An example of such a mapping (non-trivial), 
or even a homotopy of maps ($0\leq \tau\le 1$), is
(or `localized' maps $R^4=H \to S^3$)

$f(h) = \frac{q-1}{q+1}$, where $q=h\ i\ \bar{h}+\tau\ i= -\bar{q}$ ; i.e.  $\bar{f}=f^{-1}$ ;

here $h$ - quaternion, $q$ - imaginary quaternion, $f\in S^3$ - quaternion of unit length.

One can check that the framed 1-manifold $f^{-1}(-1)$ is non-trivial (see  $\tau=1$).

Motivation: to describe topological charges (and quasi-charges) in the frame field theory
(or Absolute Parallelism), see arXiv: gr-qc/0610076 .

This map is of great symmetry, in a sense like:
$f(gh\bar{g})=gf\bar{g}=f(ghg)$, where $g=e^{i\alpha/2}$.
Moreover, there is a more huge symmetry, a kind of gauge (gradient) symmetry, I quess:

$q(h)=q(h\ e^{i\alpha(h)})$ .

So, if one write quaternion $h$ as a pair of complex number (spinor),
$h=a\ e^{i\phi} + j\ b\ e^{i\psi}$, so $q=i+(a^2-b^2)i -2abe^{i(\phi-\psi)}k$,
and it is evident that the differential, combination $d\phi+d\psi$ in no way can arise in any differential form constructed from only $f$-field.

The cases $\pi_3(S^2)$ and $\pi_7(S^4)$ have the known solution relating to the Hopf invariant (if I am not mistaken) and having the form (pullback form)

$\alpha\wedge d\alpha$, where $d\alpha$ is the volume form on the sphere $S^2$ or $S^4$;

that is, for the first case, $d\alpha\propto{\rm Re}(\omega d\omega\wedge d\omega) $, where
$\omega$ is a unit imaginary quaternion, the coordinates on the $S^2$; $\omega^2=-1$.
(${\rm Tr}()$ suits (instead of ${\rm Re}()$ if the units are represented with the Pauli matrices,
$i_p=i\sigma_p$.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question.  Where does the differential form live?  Or are you asking for a map (à la Skyrme, say) $\mathbb{R}^5 \to S^3$, such that its restriction to the sphere at infinity gives the generator of $\pi_4(S^3)$?

Comment: I think Ivan Zhogin is after some differential form similar to the 3-form one can integrate on $S^3$ to get the Hopf invariant of a mapping.  So he'd want a construction of differential forms on $S^4$ from maps from $S^4$ to $S^3$ and maps from $S^4$ to $S^2$, which when integrated yielded topological invariants (mod 2, say).  Ivan, have you looked at Bott and Tu's book on Differential forms in Algebraic Topology?

Comment: How is this ever going to work? Don't differential forms only detect real homotopy?

Comment: @Daniel: actually rational homotopy (by Sullivan,...), but your objection stands.  I don't know how to probe a torsion class via differential forms.

Comment: @ jc: Yes, the question is how to calculate, to prove that the map is non-trivial (with some integration, not only a framed manifold).
2. No, I have not. Have you any link on this book? Thanks. 

Comment: You may want to look at differential characters a la Cheeger-Simons. They have forms as an ingredient, and can detect torsion. I'm not sure if they can see the classes you describe though. This may not give the answer, but point you in roughly the right direction.

Comment: @Ivan - the book jc mentions is still in print, but here is a Google books link: http://books.google.com.au/books?id=S6Ve0KXyDj8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=bott+tu&hl=en&ei=q8_gTPDrBYu4vgPzovnzDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Try to look for Bott and Tu via Google.  Homotopy groups of spheres are torsion outside of $\pi_n S^n$ and $\pi_{4n-1}S^{2n}$ so $\pi_4 S^3$ isn't detectable by standard differential form technology -- things like pull-backs, wedge products, integration, etc.

Comment: @  José Figueroa-O'Farrill  - Yes, Skyrme model and Faddeev model are the close issue.
@ David Roberts - thanks, Cheeger-Simons gives many Google-links, but.. it's not so easy.
Perhaps it's better: to consider the subset of axi-symmetrical mappings: the set of orbits is 3-ball and the stationary points (where $f(h)$ commutes with the symmetry, $g=e^{i\alpha/2}$) as its boundary, $S^2$; so we have a diad (relative) mappings  $(D^3, S^2) \to (S^3,S^1)$, which leads to the relative (or diad) homotopy group $\pi_3(S^3;S^1)$; to write 3-form of topological quasi-charge; to do something else :-)